# how do I correctly make an active record query from one table to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Been stuck on this all afternoon/evening. Would really appreciate the help as I continue to work on this.

I have two different tables. Posts (status and photo) and Places (address). I'd like to combine these (status, photo, address) into one form and one show.

So, I think I am having trouble making an Active Record Query Interface. However, I may have messed up in Associating the tables...

Post.rb Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commenters, through: :comments, source: :user
end
```

Place.rb Model

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :posts

end
```

Posts _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :upload %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :upload %>
  </div>
    <%= f.label :place %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :place %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Posts show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @post.status %></h1>
<p><%= link_to @post.upload, @post.upload %></p>
<p><%= @post.place %></p>

<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_area :response, placeholder: "Add a comment...", :rows => 8, :cols => 40 %>
  </p>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<ul class="comments">
  <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <li><%= "#{comment.user.try(:email)} posted: #{comment.response}" %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<p><%= link_to "Back to home page", root_path %></p>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
    @comment = Comment.new(:post => @post)
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end


    def create
    safe_post = params.require(:post).permit(:status, :upload)
    @post = current_user.posts.new safe_post
    @post.place = Place.from_params params[:place]
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:status, :upload)
    end
end
```

places_controller.rb

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_place, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /places
  # GET /places.json
  def index
    @places = Place.all
  end

  # GET /places/1
  # GET /places/1.json
  def show

    @place = Place.find params[:id]

  end

  # GET /places/new
  def new
    @place = Place.new
  end

  # GET /places/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /places
  # POST /places.json
  def create
    @place = Place.new(place_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.save
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /places/1
  # PATCH/PUT /places/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.update(place_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /places/1
  # DELETE /places/1.json
  def destroy
    @place.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to places_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_place
      @place = Place.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def place_params
      params.require(:place).permit(:address, :latitude, :longitude)
    end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140324213459) do

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.string   "response"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

  create_table "places", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "address"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "status"
    t.string   "upload"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "place_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["place_id"], name: "index_posts_on_place_id"
  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "photo"
    t.string   "bio"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

routes.rb

```
DondeApp::Application.routes.draw do


  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: :create
    resources :places
  end

  devise_for :users
   root 'posts#index'

  end
```

Comment: I am still missing most of your question. Which `ActiveRecord` query in what controller action gives you an unexpected result? From what I can tell you might miss some `includes` as in the [API documentation(http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) of `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: The query in the Posts controller. I tried including a reference to the Places under 'def create' ... the line: @post.place = Place.from_params params[:place]

Comment: Well you keep me guessing what query you mean, but I will stick to the query in the `show` action for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need  nested model form, look up this http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try to access `@post.place` in your `_form.html.erb` which might actually work through `AREL` magic, but you will probably get some strange results putting it into a `text_field`. Usually you would use a select box to select from existing places or whip up a `jQuery` control to find the right reference.

So the query in your `show` action should actually work to produce a suitable `Post` object, given it was set up correctly in the `create` action. You do have some code in there using `Place.from_params` to create a new place using a mysterious `params[:place]` that does not seem to be permitted (for the `Post` object that is). As your form only contains a `text_field` to refer to the `place` I have my doubts that this will work.

Check out your `Post` objects in the rails console and see wether the refer to a valid `Place` object. If they do you have to reflect this in your view, accessing the `place` attribute of your `@post` object will return a whole object which does not "know" how to present itself in a `text_field`, much less to create itself from one.

I *guess* this is the main problem you are having, but it is difficult to tell if you do not tell us what you expect and what you get instead.

Given this, you could *optimize* your AREL-queries to use `includes(:place)` in order to avoid the `n+1` queries problem, but that would just apply to your `index` action. Otherwise I *think* AREL has you mostly covered.

Comment: Thanks for replying... Since my post, I set this up as a nested model form via the suggestion of @jhon cortes. Initially I followed the railscast. Then tried it again using this [link](http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/) article... so its a little different now - including the params, which I think make a lot more sense now, in my posts controller: 
`code
def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:id, :place_id, :status, :upload,
        :places_attributes => [:id, :address, :latitude, :longitude])
    end
`

Comment: now i think my main problem, is, in the show.html.erb about how to retrieve the :address info and display it. I'm trying to display the address text using this code in my view `code  <p><%= @place.address %></p>`. The error on that code is: "NoMethodError in Posts#show" and "undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: In your controller you only assign `@post` and `@comment` so there is no point in accessing `@place`, it will always be `nil` (and it should stay that way). However you will be able to access `@post.place.address` which might even make sense in a `text_field`. However you would probably create new places all the time, even in two places were the same if you create them based on some `params` in `Post#create`.